# Vim: Can I use dashes instead of tildes for empty lines?

Tags: vim

Just started trying to get serious with vim. The big thing everyone raves about with vim is "you can configure everything!" and I do like tweaking little things about my environment. One of the first things that bugged me was the tildes(`~`) on the left hand side of the screen for empty lines. I'd like to change these to dashes(`-`), but I can't for the life of me figure out how?

Comment: There is a *lot* in Vim that is not configurable. You will be much happier if you adapt to Vim's expectations, than trying to make Vim adapt to yours.

Comment: Although I'm rather surprised that this is not configurable when there's `fillchars` and `showbreak` etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, not possible to change `~` to any other character.

If `~` is bugging you, you might like to hide it by `NonText highlight` group that is used for displaying them by setting foreground color same with background color:

```
:highlight NonText ctermfg=bg guifg=bg
```

Unfortunately, this too has repercussions, see `:h list` for a example.

Coming back, It seems to me best to adapt to the tiny `~`, Some think, it is beautiful :)

P.S. Based on Josh's finding, Have opened a issue [#4181](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4181) at neovim repo

Answer (score 3):

The `~` is hard-coded. If you're willing to rebuild vim from source, you could probably do it by modifying the `win_draw_end` call that exists at the end of the (rather epic) `win_update` function in `screen.c`. It is, specifically, on [line 2142 as of this writing](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/screen.c#L2142).

(Since rebuilding from source is a bit extreme, Deleisha's suggestion of "hiding" the `~` via appropriate syntax highlighting is probably *far* better for the typical user.)

Comment: @Deleisha It seems like it might be simple enough to offer a patch to make this tweakable, although that implies to me that there's a reason it hasn't been done yet. I'll dig around.